# Python script running as screen process gets "Killed" on Ubuntu / AWS EC2

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to have a python script running on my Ubuntu instance constantly. It's an AWS EC2 a1.medium instance and the script is taking pretty much 100% of the CPU constantly.

I start the script with `screen <run script>`, however it gets killed randomly and I have no idea why. One time I had it running in the foreground and I saw "Killed" as the last output of the process.

I tried running it as root with `sudo screen <run script>` but I get `[screen is terminating]`. Not sure if root would even help though.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this? I tried with `-L -Logfile <filename>` with proper permissions for the file, but it stays empty, so I really have no idea how to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What is nature of your script? Is it CPU/Memory bound ?
I am assuming you are over utilising vCPUs provide in a1.medium EC2 instance

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195206/9592801) to understand steal time

Comment: The script consumes a web API, about 1MB/sec worth of data, processes and writes a small amount of data in a postgres database. I picked the A1 family of instances because they don't have a credit system and you can use the vCPU as much as you like.

Comment: Okay so its I/O, can you please share script so that can make an attempt to handle errors or can take a look if something can be done to catch that errors ?

Comment: Are you running consumer script under `while True` ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have any issues on my machine with that script, it could run for days without interrupting.

Comment: Maybe I should look into this - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/ - "Services may be respawned if they die unexpectedly" but it looks like a bandaid rather than fixing the issue.

Comment: I made you a pastebin of the script if you want to take a look - https://pastebin.com/WuSJ0LvL

Comment: Thanks for sharing clean readable code. I suspect there is some exceptions are raised in threads. Can you please take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779560/9592801 plan to handle exceptions and give a try ?